# Does the READPAST hint have to be used within a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Or can it be used in a normal select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used in a `SELECT` statement not in an explicit transaction.

Comment: +1 true, but It can also be used in other statements, like `UPDATE`